# Matrices similar only to themselves

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Find all matrices similar *only* to themselves, i.e., $PTP^{-1}=T$ for any invertible $P$.

My attempt: $PT = TP$.

Am I going about this correctly? If so, how do I find all matrices that are commutative (where $P$ is invertible)?

Comment: Hint: for **any** square matrix $\;A\;$ , $\;IAI^{-1}=A\;,\;\;I:=$ the identity matrix

Comment: @Timbuc thanks! However, I am looking for matrices similar $\underline{\textrm{only}}$ to themselves.

Comment: @Timbuc, $PIP^{-1} = I.$ Not sure there are any others, just $tI.$

Comment: @WillJagy I am aware of $I$ and $0$

Comment: If $T$ is only similar to itself, we have $PT=TP$ for all *invertible* matrices $P$. Since invertible matrices span all square matrices, it follows that $T$ commute with every square matrix. It is well known that such a matrix $T$ must be a scalar matrix, i.e. a scalar multiple of the identity matrix. See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/795326/a-matrix-m-that-commutes-with-any-matrix-is-of-the-form-m-alpha-i), for instance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let us denote the elements of $T$, $P$, and $X := PTP^{-1}$ as $t_{ij}$, $p_{ij}$, and $x_{ij}$ respectively.

Assume that $T$ is not diagonal. That means that $t_{ij} \ne 0$ for some $i \ne j$. Now, let $P$ be the same as identity except for $p_{ii} = 2$, i.e.,

$$P = \operatorname{diag}(\underbrace{1,\dots,1}_{i-1},2,\underbrace{1,\dots,1}_{n-i}).$$

Then

$$P^{-1} = \operatorname{diag}(\underbrace{1,\dots,1}_{i-1},1/2,\underbrace{1,\dots,1}_{n-i}).$$

It is easy to see that

$$x_{ij} = p_{ii} \cdot t_{ij} \cdot p_{jj}^{-1} = 2t_{ij} \ne t_{ij}.$$

Hence, $T$ must be a diagonal matrix.

Let us now assume that there exist $i,j$ such that $t_{ii} \ne t_{jj}$. In this case, let $P$ be the identity matrix with $i$-th and $j$-th rows (or columns) swapped. In this case, $P$ is a permutation (so, $P^{-1} = P^T$) and $X$ is obtained from $T$ by swapping $i$-th and $j$-th elements of the diagonal, so $X \ne T$.

In other words, $T = \lambda I$ for some $\lambda$. This is a necessary condition.

To check that it is also a sufficient one, we need to check that every such $T$ satisfies what we want. This is easy:

$$PTP^{-1} = P(\lambda I)P^{-1} = \lambda PP^{-1} = \lambda I = T.$$

Comment: Nice! Didn't think of this in my comment. +1